# Global memory for work item cache

Tags: opencl

Due to to local memory limitations, I need to use global memory as cache for my work items.

Suppose I have 1000 work groups with 64 work items each. Each item needs 4K cache. Cache doesn't need to persist after work item completes.

I will allocate one single global memory buffer and assign 4K pieces to the work items.

(I am targeting AMD GPUs)

What is the minimum size I would need to guarantee that there would not be
any concurrency issues between work items?

Since AMD has <= 64 CUs, my guess is

64 * 128 * 4000 bytes, and use (global work item ID % (64*128)) 
to assign a cache chunk to a work item.

Comment: you can try and profile that with codexl. it tells you necessary conditions about a kernel, where the bottlenecks are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each cache item(accessed by  `global work item ID % (64*128)`) is a struct 4000 bytes-long, and if implementation doesn't force each struct to be aligned on 4096 bytes, and if cache line size is not an exact divisor of 4000 and if global memory banks stride length is not exact divisor of 4000, then it shouldn't be a problem.

---

Profiled this kernel with codexl,(took 0.5s for 16k workitems):

```
    __kernel void test(__global float * a)
    {
        int i=get_global_id(0)*4096;
        for(int j=0;j<4096;j++)
            a[i+j]*=2.0f;
    }
```

and some of the output:

- mem units stalled %55
- cache hit %45
- mem unit busy %99
- valu busy %0.05

then changed the kernel to interleaved type(executed in 0.25s):

```
    __kernel void test(__global float * a)
    {
        int i=get_global_id(0);
        for(int j=0;j<4096;j++)
            a[i+j*4096*4]*=2.0f;
    }
```

- mem units stalled %57
- cache hit %47
- mem unit busy %84
- valu busy %1.5

so interleaved mode puts less strain on mem unit and hits cache a tad more often and ALU parts get fed more often and finishes %50 quicker.

Then tried this:

```
__kernel void test(__global float * a)
{
    int i=get_global_id(0)*4100;
    for(int j=0;j<4100;j++)
        a[i+j]*=2.0f;
}
```

this took 0.37s, %30 faster than 4096 version but with higher mem unit stalls(the end point non-alignment must have caused this to waste some cycles on unnecessary data-fetches) and cache hit reduced to %37.

Test GPU is R7-240

---

Last test with structs:

```
typedef struct test_struct
{
   float test_field[4096];
}strr;
__kernel void test(__global strr * a)
{
    int i=get_global_id(0);
    for(int j=0;j<4096;j++)
    a[i].test_field[j]*=2.0f;
}
```

this completed in 0.53 seconds and had similar profiling data as strided kernel at the beginning.

empty kernel executes in 0.25 seconds so its not loading whole struct with this. Only needed elements are read.

---

Profiling for interleaved group-centric global accesses:

```
typedef struct test_struct
{
   float test_field[4096];
}strr;
__kernel void test(__global strr * a)
{
    int iLocal=get_local_id(0);
    int iGroup=get_group_id(0);
    for(int j=0;j<64;j++)
    a[iGroup].test_field[iLocal+j*64]*=2.0f;
}
```

0.25s again so it is as fast as it can be.

Cache hit: %44
Mem unit busy: %82
Mem unit stalled: %67
Valu busy: %0.9

so it has best conditions of all, even without caching.

Comment: Thanks. I mean 4096 bytes for cache chunk. But, is there a guarantee that work items are scheduled in a certain sequence, based on global work item id ? If that is the case, then I can be sure that I don't have two work items using same cache chunk

Comment: if a work item can use all line resources in a compute unit, it shouldn't be a problem but I am less inclined to that so they could more probably be accessing in parallel. I can't have any guarantee about that.  128x64 is 8k so more work items than 8k will have multiple accesses to same cache element (big gpu can have it in several clocks, having 4k cores)

Comment: Thanks. So, are you saying that to be safe, I should allocate a 4096 block for each work item? I would like to re-use the same cache block for multiple work items, but only if it can be guaranteed that the work items do not access the block concurrently

Comment: AMD's own forum says large power of 2's stride is bad. Because only a few lines are used they say. 4000 should be good or 4103 maybe. To overcome such things. But you can use interleaved cache too. Such that first workitem access 1st byte, 10000thbyte ..... 4096000th byte for all 4096bytes of cachhe data of itself. And this would let explicit memory request balancing, if not implicit already.

Comment: Thanks a lot for profiling these kernels. I'm sorry, I think I may have not explained the problem clearly. I have 64 work items per work group, and all work items share a single cache buffer. Access is designed so that reads are coalesced across the work items. i.e. each work item owns a single vertical line of array points in the cache. So, item 0 owns 0,64,128,..... and item 1 owns 1,65,129,   etc. So, reads are coalesced.

Comment: That would increase cache hit ratio. But you said each item needed it and said global work item ID % (64*128)) . Now I profiled for that at the end

Comment: Yes, my mistake, sorry. Thanks. So, interleaved is the best approach.

Comment: Just like working on cpu. But with greater limits. I will test some more testing in time, maybe tomorrow with better results.

Comment: Yes. Thanks again. Another question: because this is a cache, I will be reading and writing to the buffer. But, each work item has it's own dedicated region in the cache - there is no sharing of data between work items. So, do I need a global memory barrier after write, before next read ?

Comment: When I could use local memory for cache, I didn't need local barriers, because work group size was equal to 64

Comment: I've read the results wrong, its not caching. But its even faster than first kernel. Caching %44. I  forgot local size at 256. But even that was faster than others. Coalesced reads are good. local size = 64

Comment: If item writes and only it reads later, no barrier needed. why don't you use private memory? it is 256kB per compute unit

Comment: Thanks. Glad to hear I can skip the barriers. As for private memory, this is a precious resource and don't want to use it all up - want to keep occupancy as high as possible.

Comment: you are right. it hides memory operations' latency through many wavefronts in-flight computing